# Combinatorics Catastrophe

Tags: additive-combinatorics

**How will you solve**

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{2i \choose i}\;?$$

I tried to use *Coefficient Method* but couldn't get it! Also I searched for *Christmas Stocking Theorem* but to no use ...

Comment: What do you mean with *solve*?

Comment: It implies give an expression in terms of n.

Comment: If I now replace ${2i \choose i}$ with $C_{i}$ the _i_-Catalan number then how will you compute the sum basic working!

Answer (score 4):

This is [OEIS A006134](http://oeis.org/A006134); the generating function is

$$g(x)=\frac1{(1-x)\sqrt{1-4x}}\;,$$

but no closed form is given. There is an approximation

$$a(n)\sim\frac{2^{2n+2}}{3\sqrt{\pi n}}\;.$$

**Correction:** It’s one less than the sequence from OEIS, whose terms include $\binom00=1$.

Comment: Can I apply _Chu-Vandermonde Identity_ here?

Comment: @Bakshinder: I don’t see how. By the way, if you replace the central binomial coefficients with the Catalan numbers, you get [OEIS A014137](http://oeis.org/A014137), which also appears to be quite intractable.

Comment: __Can you guide me how to approach these types of sequences?__ *Elementary guidelines.*

Comment: @Bakshinder: Judging from the OEIS entries and the rather ugly closed form in Robert Israel’s answer, I don’t think that elementary methods will take you very far with these sequences. Frankly, when I get one that gives me trouble, I do what I did here: calculate a few terms and look it up in OEIS.

Comment: It is actually [A066796](http://oeis.org/A066796) and double [A079309](http://oeis.org/A079309)

Comment: @Henry: It also isn’t the right sequence. The OP is adding central binomial coefficients.

Comment: @Brian I think it is ${2 \choose 1},{2 \choose 1}+{4 \choose 2},{2 \choose 1}+{4 \choose 2}+{6 \choose 3},...$ i.e. $2,2+6,2+6+20,...$ i.e. $2,8,28,...$.  What do you think it is?

Comment: @Henry: Exactly what you think it is, which isn’t A079309. Your comment didn’t mention A066796 when I responded to it; it identified the sequence as A079309. The sequence is of course A066796; it is also one less than A006134.

Comment: @Brian - We may as well stop here.  When you replied, my comment said "It is actually [http://oeis.org/A066796](A066796)" which I then corrected as I had messed up the link markdown

Comment: @Henry: You misunderstood me. I’m not talking about the mistyped link. I’m talking about the comment that now reads *It is actually A066796 and double A079309*. That comment did not mention A066796 when I first saw and responded to it; it mentioned only A079309 and said nothing about *double*. I assume that you made an edit that was quick enough to beat the 5-minute deadline but slow enough that I didn’t see it until you brought it to my attention with your *I think it is* comment.

Comment: @Brian I am certain you are wrong about what happened (I am sure I mentioned A066796 on its own initially), and you seem equally certain I am wrong.  It isn't helpful and it does not matter now.

Answer (score 1):

Maple gives a "closed form" involving a hypergeometric function:
$$ -1-{2\,n+2\choose n+1}\; {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,n+\frac32;\,n+2;\,4)}-\frac{i
\sqrt {3}}{3}
$$